# Functional equation: $f(x^2+f(y))=y+f^2(x)$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, functional-equations

> > **Functional Equation:**
>
> Solve for a given function $f:R\rightarrow R$, $$f(x^2+f(y))=y+f^2(x)\tag{$\ast$}$$
> *Note*: $f^2(x)=f(x)\cdot f(x)$.

Not sure if the proof is correct (I have made quite a few fake proofs):

---

**My Attempt:**

Fix $x$ to show $f$ is surjective, and assume $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$. Then, sub $y=y_1$ and $y=y_2$ to show $f$ is injective. Therefore, $f$ is bijective.

One may find a $k$ such that $f(k)=0$. Sub into $(*)$, giving $$f(k^2+f(y))=y.$$ Now, one may find $m$ such that $f(m)=-k^2$. Sub it in to obtain $f(0)=m$. Therefore, we have the following simultaneous equation: $$\begin{align}f(f(0))&=-k^2 \\ \text{and }\qquad f(k)&=0.\end{align}$$ Set $x=y=0$, giving $f(f(0))=f^2(0)$. So we have $f^2(0)=-k^2$. Since the LHS$\,\ge0$ and RHS$\,\le0$, then $f^2(0)=-k^2=0$ and thus, $f(0)=0$.

Now set $x=0$ to obtain that $f(f(y))=y$. In other words, $f$ is an involution.

Now set $y=0$ to obtain $f(x^2)=f^2(x)$. Thus, $f^2(-x)=f(x^2)=f^2(x)$. Since $f$ is injective, then $f(x)\neq f(-x)$. Therefore, $f(x)=-f(-x)$. In other words, $f$ is odd.

Set $y=f(x^2)$ in $(*)$ to obtain that $f(2x^2)=2f(x^2)$. Set $x=1$ and $y=0$ in $(*)$ to obtain $f(1)=1$. Set $c=x^2$ to obtain $f(2c)=2f(c)$. Therefore, $$\forall x>0, \ f(x)=x\text{ is the only solution.}$$ Since $f$ is an odd function, I claim that $f(x)=x$ is certainly the only solution.

Edit: new last step
Sub $x=f(z)$ and $y=0$ in $(*)$ gives $$f(z^2)=z^2$$ Since $f$ is an odd function, $f(x)=x$ is the only solution.

Comment: There is a typo: Set $y=f(x)$ in $(*)$ to obtain that $f(2x^2)=2f(x^2)$. I guess you mean set $y=f(x^2)$.

Comment: @user260822 $c$ is a real number (which is always positive), and I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly derived that $f$ is odd, that $f^2(x)=f(x^2)$, and that $f$ is an involution.
From the latter, you have
$$f(x^2+y)=f(y)+f^2(x) $$
and therefore
$$\tag1z\ge y\implies f(z)\ge f(y).$$
By induction (mimicking part of the work for Cauchy's equation), $$\tag2 f(nz)=nf(z)$$
for $n\in\Bbb N$ and $z\ge0$.
Indeed, this is clear for $n=1$, and with $x=\sqrt{z}$ and $y=nz$, we get the induction step: $f(z+nz)=f(nz)+f^2(\sqrt{z})=nf(z)+f(\sqrt z^2)=(n+1)f(z)$.
Using that $f$ is odd, $(2)$ also holds for $z<0$, as well as for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. From $0\ne f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)^2$, we get $f(1)=1$, hence $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$.
Now let $x$ be any real with $\frac mn\le x\le\frac{m+1}n$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$, $n\in\Bbb N$. $m\le nx<m+1$ and by $(1)$
$$ m=f(m)\le f(nx)=nf(x)\le f(m+1)=m+1$$
i.e.
$$ \frac mn\le f(x)\le \frac{m+1}n.$$
As we can make the rational approximations arbitrarily good, we conclude that $$f(x)=x$$ for all $x$.

Comment: But isn't it possible to make rational approximations in Cauchy's function equation? So if it works here, why doesn't work in Cauchy's functional equations? Please explain as I am a bit confused.

Comment: Since Hagen showed that the function is monotonic, then he found that f(any irrational number) is bounded by rational numbers. and then by the density of rational numbers, it has to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your proof are correct. However, your last claim is not justified.

The following is a simpler proof. Once you have proven that $f^2(x)=f(x^2)$ and $f(f(y))=y$, you have 
$$f(x^2 +f(f(y)))= f(x^2 +y ) = f(y) + f(x^2) $$

Then by replacing $x^2 \to x$ (but keeping that $x>0$ in mind) you have 
 $f(x +y ) = f(x)+ f(y)$
with $x>0$. Everything now is similar to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Also with $f(1)=1$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$, you can be able to fix the freedom in Cauchy's solution and prove that $f(x) =x$ for all rational $x$.

Comment: But Cauchy has a lot more solutions ...

Comment: He has $f(1) =1 $ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ therefore completely fix the freedom in Cauchy's problem.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not see where you pulled continuity from.

Comment: Oh, good point. There is no such assumption in the problem. Then my statement above only applies to rational number.